# Java Event Listener on Clock Minute change

Tags: java, timer

I am looking for the best way in Java to monitor the computer clock (the minutes) and to fire off a method/thread every time it changes.

So if the time is 13:20 and it changes to 13.21 then do something. So any time there is a minute change some code gets fired.

What is the best way to listen to the minute section of the clock for changes ?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Find the current system time using System.currentTimeMillis()
2. Calculate how many milliseconds until the next minute
3. Schedule a TimerTask on a Timer to run in that number of milliseconds in the future
4. In that TimerTask's event handler schedule a new reoccurring TimerTask to run every 60,000 milliseconds.

   ```
   int milisInAMinute = 60000;
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

   Runnable update = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           // Do whatever you want to do when the minute changes
       }
   };

   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
           update.run();
       }
   }, time % milisInAMinute, milisInAMinute);

   // This will update for the current minute, it will be updated again in at most one minute.
   update.run();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org). You can do this using the following cron expression:

`0 * * * * ?`

Answer (score 1):

`Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Then you can get the minutes by `d.getMinutes()`. Have a check running in a thread waiting for the value of `d.getMinutes()` to change.

Comment: This involves a lot of busy waiting.

Comment: @Charlie that depends on precision you want. Just use a [wait(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) in a checking cycle.

Comment: That is still busy waiting. The clock would be off by between -checkCycle and +checkCycle.

Comment: @Charlie any solution

Comment: For this specific answer? no. I have an answer below that does the trick.